# How to write a function that computes the maximum and minimum of a list of integers using Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am new to scheme. I am trying to find max and min of a list using scheme. Using "loop" I was able get the answer. Now I am trying different way to implement the same thing. I made some changes and  for some reason I can't find what I am doing wrong.

```
    ;non working version  
    (define (min-max list1)
    (let (ls list1) (max (car list1)) (min(car list1))
      (cond 
         ((null? ls) 
                (list "max: " max "min: " min))
         ((> (car ls) max) 
             (let ((car ls) max))
             (min-max (cdr ls))) 
         ((< (car ls) min) 
             (let ((car ls) min))
              (min-max (cdr ls)))
        (else
              (min-max (cdr ls))))))
    (define list1(list 1 2 3 4 ))
    (display list1)
    (newline)
    (min-max list1)

    ;working version
    (define (min list1)
       (let loop((ls list1) (max (car list1)) (min(car list1)))
        (cond 
         ((null? ls) 
                (list "max: " max "min: " min))
          ((> (car ls) max) 
             (loop (cdr ls)(car ls) min))
         ((< (car ls) min) 
             (loop (cdr ls) max (car ls) ))
        (else 
              (loop (cdr ls) max min)))))

        (define list1(list 1 2 3 4 ))

        (display list1)
        (newline)
        (min list1)
```

Comment: There are so many errors with this code that I don't know where to start. Wrong syntax, parentheses mistakes, incorrect function calls, non-existent procedures... I'd suggest you start by reading a good text book on Scheme, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I trying to learn scheme from online tutorials. I added a working version above. I was trying to find if there is any way run multiple expressions after a condition statement. Please let me know if you can direct me to any suitable material. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Notice that in the working version there is a named `let` (you named it `loop`). It creates a procedure with the the variable names so that you can have the current minimum while going through the list. In your attemt to do both min and max you'll need the current result as variables in the same manner.

Comment: There are two good books freely available online; [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org) ("HtDP"), and [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) ("SICP").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Code Review but I'll start with the "working" version of your procedure first. As is stands that procedure doesn't work for empty lists, so you should add a test for that. Then, no need to re-compare the first element of the list to `min` and `max`. Then, you seem to think that `loop` is a keyword, so I've changed the name to `helper`. Finally, I've modified it to be less repetitive:

```
(define (min-max lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (let helper ((lst (cdr lst)) (min (car lst)) (max (car lst)))
        (if (null? lst)
            (list min max)
            (let ((c (car lst)))
              (helper (cdr lst)
                      (if (< c min) c min)
                      (if (> c max) c max)))))))
```

which is the same as

```
(define (min-max lst)
  (define (helper lst min max)
    (if (null? lst)
        (list min max)
        (let ((c (car lst)))
          (helper (cdr lst)
                  (if (< c min) c min)
                  (if (> c max) c max)))))
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (helper (cdr lst) (car lst) (car lst))))
```

Testing:

```
> (min-max '(1 2 3 4))
'(1 4)
> (min-max '(1 8 2 3 4))
'(1 8)
> (min-max '())
'()
```

Your first procedure doesn't work because at each recursive call you re-initialize `min` and `max`. Also, since there is no test for the empty list, inevitably you end up taking the `car` of the empty list, which is not allowed in Scheme. Finally, it looks like you want to change the value of `min` and `max` outside the recursive call, which means you have to use `set!`. Here's a working version of that:

```
(define (min-max lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (let ((min (car lst)) (max (car lst)))
        (define (helper lst)
          (if (null? lst)
              (list min max)
              (let ((c (car lst)))
                (when (< c min) (set! min c))
                (when (> c max) (set! max c))
                (helper (cdr lst)))))
        (helper lst))))
```

This yields the same results, but you can see how much less elegant the code looks with `set!` as compared to the recursive call to `helper`.

Comment: Why shouldn't it fail when passing an empty list? IMO evaluating to nil would just more the problem away from the source of the upcoming error since there are no min and max of an empty list of numbers.

Comment: @Sylwester Well I guess we don't agree on this then ;-)

Comment: @uselpa Thanks a lot. Your answer clarified my confusion.